# Turn off swap for single program. Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, swap

Can I turn off using swap for single program? Visual Studio for example.
Or set high priority of using memory by this program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an Visual Studio addin which does what you want:

[**Unswap Memory**](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2cfd12ae-f070-4182-9211-23d11aeecc35?SRC=VSIDE)

```
Forced load Visual Studio 2010 in physical memory from the paging file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the [SetProcessWorkingSetSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms686234%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function in the win32 API which might achive what you want?

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it is not exactly what I want. I want to configure it using windows tools or by making some changes in registry.